# How to check elements created by generator when debugging a python project?

Tags: python

I use PyCharm to realize a program which is aimed to generate primes. Code like this:

```
def _odd_iter():
    n = 1
    while True:
        yield n
        n = n + 2


def _not_divisible(n):
    return lambda x: x % n > 0


def primes():
    it = _odd_iter()
    yield 2
    while True:
        i = next(it)
        yield i
        it = filter(_not_divisible, it) # !!!!!!!!!!don't know how it works!!!!!!!!!!

for n in primes():
    if n < 1000:
        print(n)
    else:
        break
```

For me the annotated code is obscure, I dont know how it works and whether it is right, so I add a breakpoint on it and determine to debug. But it is a generator, I cannot see the detail numbers. What can I do?

Comment: You don't need the debugger. Just do `for p in primes(): print p`. Recommend you add a `break` statement for `p` becomes bigger than, say 1000. Else it will go on forever.

Comment: You can evaluate expression and `list(it)`.

Comment: I'm interested why one cannot put a breakpoint with generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `filter(function or None, iterable)` --> filter object
>
> Return an iterator yielding those items of iterable for which `function(item)` is true. If function is `None`, return the items that are true.

You can't see the details because it returns an iterable object, do this to see what it returns:

```
it = list(filter(_not_divisible, it)) # or next(filter(...))
```